# Is it possible to download a tar file using Yum

Tags: linux, yum

We have a tar file in one of the Satellite Repositories which I want to download

```
yum insatll --downloadonly --downloaddir = /tmp/lucidworks
```

Works fine but downaloads a package to my /tmp directory in the rpm format.

The file which I want to download has a different name to pacakge and has .tar.gz extension

Is there any command to downaload the tar file ?

Comment: something like this `yum install httpd -y --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp/lucidworks`

Answer (score 0):

you cant download tar directly but you can use `yumdownloader` package to download and tar with a pipe

install yumdownloader with yum-utils

`yum -y install yum-utils.noarch`

`yumdownloader httpd`

you can extract rpm file with `rpm2cpio`